# String.Join dropping null values returning less items than number of Elements in the Array

Tags: c#

Given this method, The resulting string created drops the consecutive null values.  Is th `??` being used wrong below?  It's behaving as if it is concatentating all consectively indexed null values before returning

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> ToCsv<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> objectlist)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(T).GetFields();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            yield return String.Join(separator, fields.Select(f => f.Name).Union(properties.Select(p => p.Name)).ToArray());
            foreach (var o in objectlist)
            {
                var pp = properties.Select(
                    p => (p.GetValue(o, null) ?? String.Empty));

                var val = string.Join(separator, fields.Select(f => (f.GetValue(o)).ToString() )
                    .Union(pp).ToArray());
                ;
                yield return val;
            }
        }
```

Here is my array

[0]"0001020003"
[1]"Bob Jones"
[2] NULL
[3] NULL
[4] "Longboat"

With that array the joined string created is...

"0001020003,Bob Jones,,Longboat"

Comment: Testing that in Linqpad with `string[] foo = new [] {"0001020003","Bob Jones",null,null,"Longboat"};string.Join(",",foo).Dump();` I get the expected result. You should always try testing things first. In this case I'd also try making the array before `string.Join` so you can easily examine what is in the array that you are passing to help determine where the error lies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Enumerable.Union` excludes duplicates, so you are only getting a single blank instance returned.

Try using [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.